# Finding percentile_cont

Tags: sql, postgresql

Hope I can express this clearly.

I am using the pgAdmin 4 tool in PostgreSQL 12.

I am going through end of chapter (6) exercises in the book "Practical SQL" by Anthony DeBarros and am having problem getting my query to run.

There are two tables with (total) population per county per state and I want to find the median percent change from 2000 to 2010.

(p0010001 is the population from each table by state & county)

The result I want is just the median as "50th Percentile".

Thank you for any help you can offer!

The table for 2000 (2010 is the larger but this query doesn't need all the fields)

```
CREATE TABLE us_counties_2000 (
    geo_name varchar(90),              -- County/state name,
    state_us_abbreviation varchar(2),  -- State/U.S. abbreviation
    state_fips varchar(2),             -- State FIPS code
    county_fips varchar(3),            -- County code
    p0010001 integer,                  -- Total population
    p0010002 integer,                  -- Population of one race:
    p0010003 integer,                      -- White Alone
    p0010004 integer,                      -- Black or African American alone
    p0010005 integer,                      -- American Indian and Alaska Native alone
    p0010006 integer,                      -- Asian alone
    p0010007 integer,                      -- Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander alone
    p0010008 integer,                      -- Some Other Race alone
    p0010009 integer,                  -- Population of two or more races
    p0010010 integer,                  -- Population of two races
    p0020002 integer,                  -- Hispanic or Latino
    p0020003 integer                   -- Not Hispanic or Latino:
);
```

Sample lines of data (from 2000):

```
geo_name,state_us_abbreviation,state_fips,county_fips,p0010001,p0010002,p0010003,p0010004,p0010005,p0010006,p0010007,p0010008,p0010009,p0010010,p0020002,p0020003
"Autauga County, Alabama",AL,01,001,43671,43266,35221,7473,194,200,13,165,405,388,610,43061
"Baldwin County, Alabama",AL,01,003,140415,138949,122366,14444,809,537,38,755,1466,1418,2466,137949
"Barbour County, Alabama",AL,01,005,29038,28826,14887,13451,131,84,8,265,212,195,478,28560
"Bibb County, Alabama",AL,01,007,20826,20719,15966,4624,49,17,2,61,107,105,210,20616
"Blount County, Alabama",AL,01,009,51024,50505,48512,606,250,71,12,1054,519,501,2718,48306
"Bullock County, Alabama",AL,01,011,11714,11632,2958,8564,44,21,2,43,82,74,322,11392
"Butler County, Alabama",AL,01,013,21399,21315,12492,8732,45,35,0,11,84,76,143,21256
"Calhoun County, Alabama",AL,01,015,112249,111168,88537,20810,445,633,76,667,1081,1016,1753,110496
```

Sample lines from 2010:

```
NAME,STUSAB,SUMLEV,REGION,DIVISION,STATE,COUNTY,AREALAND,AREAWATR,POP100,HU100,INTPTLAT,INTPTLON,P0010001,P0010002,P0010003,P0010004,P0010005,P0010006,P0010007,P0010008,P0010009,P0010010,P0010011,P0010012,P0010013,P0010014,P0010015,P0010016,P0010017,P0010018,P0010019,P0010020,P0010021,P0010022,P0010023,P0010024,P0010025,P0010026,P0010047,P0010063,P0010070,P0020001,P0020002,P0020003,P0020004,P0020005,P0020006,P0020007,P0020008,P0020009,P0020010,P0020011,P0020012,P0020028,P0020049,P0020065,P0020072,P0030001,P0030002,P0030003,P0030004,P0030005,P0030006,P0030007,P0030008,P0030009,P0030010,P0030026,P0030047,P0030063,P0030070,P0040001,P0040002,P0040003,P0040004,P0040005,P0040006,P0040007,P0040008,P0040009,P0040010,P0040011,P0040012,P0040028,P0040049,P0040065,P0040072,H0010001,H0010002,H0010003
    Autauga County,AL,050,3,6,01,001,1539582278,25775735,54571,22135,+32.5363818,-086.6444901,54571,53702,42855,9643,232,474,32,466,869,814,219,262,177,11,50,32,19,9,16,0,0,5,5,8,1,49,6,0,0,54571,1310,53261,52500,42154,9595,217,467,22,45,761,719,36,6,0,0,39958,39530,31910,6767,180,346,23,304,428,404,22,2,0,0,39958,828,39130,38746,31461,6738,169,341,15,22,384,363,19,2,0,0,22135,20221,1914
    Baldwin County,AL,050,3,6,01,003,4117521611,1133190229,182265,104061,+30.6592183,-087.7460666,182265,179542,156153,17105,1216,1348,89,3631,2723,2583,658,1035,336,35,311,63,34,7,38,12,0,15,11,14,14,128,11,1,0,182265,7992,174273,171976,152200,16966,1146,1340,79,245,2297,2205,87,5,0,0,140367,138905,122238,12272,923,1002,70,2400,1462,1398,60,3,1,0,140367,5186,135181,133937,119671,12193,876,994,62,141,1244,1198,46,0,0,0,104061,73180,30881
    Barbour County,AL,050,3,6,01,005,2291818968,50864716,27457,11829,+31.8706701,-085.4054562,27457,27199,13180,12875,114,107,29,894,258,254,76,49,7,2,34,54,2,4,7,0,1,2,1,5,10,3,0,0,1,27457,1387,26070,25861,12837,12820,60,107,24,13,209,206,2,0,0,1,21442,21275,10855,9647,86,80,24,583,167,163,3,0,0,1,21442,925,20517,20382,10624,9605,47,80,21,5,135,132,2,0,0,1,11829,9820,2009
    Bibb County,AL,050,3,6,01,007,1612480789,9289057,22915,8981,+33.0158929,-087.1271475,22915,22712,17381,5047,64,22,13,185,203,195,50,77,16,3,16,9,13,5,4,0,0,2,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,22915,406,22509,22328,17191,5024,64,22,7,20,181,175,6,0,0,0,17714,17584,13403,3975,47,14,11,134,130,128,2,0,0,0,17714,310,17404,17284,13247,3963,47,14,5,8,120,119,1,0,0,0,8981,7953,1028
    Blount County,AL,050,3,6,01,009,1669961855,15157440,57322,23887,+33.9774479,-086.5672464,57322,56638,53068,761,307,117,38,2347,684,662,112,330,74,8,102,12,2,0,6,3,0,2,4,7,0,21,1,0,0,57322,4626,52696,52129,50952,724,285,115,18,35,567,547,19,1,0,0,43216,42810,40515,549,227,91,23,1405,406,394,12,0,0,0,43216,2724,40492,40141,39285,524,212,89,14,17,351,341,10,0,0,0,23887,21578,2309
    Bullock County,AL,050,3,6,01,011,1613056905,6056528,10914,4493,+32.1017589,-085.7172613,10914,10828,2507,7666,23,20,43,569,86,82,12,28,3,0,3,8,5,2,9,0,0,3,0,0,9,4,0,0,0,10914,777,10137,10078,2392,7637,20,20,4,5,59,56,3,0,0,0,8484,8432,2164,5838,21,17,31,361,52,49,3,0,0,0,8484,485,7999,7963,2102,5821,18,17,3,2,36,33,3,0,0,0,4493,3745,748
    Butler County,AL,050,3,6,01,013,2011976894,2726814,20947,9964,+31.7516670,-086.6819689,20947,20786,11399,9095,60,177,7,48,161,153,58,41,17,1,13,10,4,3,3,0,0,3,0,0,0,8,0,0,0,20947,191,20756,20614,11324,9047,59,174,7,3,142,139,3,0,0,0,15891,15811,9109,6504,44,119,3,32,80,76,4,0,0,0,15891,130,15761,15694,9062,6468,43,117,3,1,67,65,2,0,0,0,9964,8491,1473
    Calhoun County,AL,050,3,6,01,015,1569189995,16624267,118572,53289,+33.7717061,-085.8225133,118572,116597,88840,24382,540,845,96,1894,1975,1848,676,520,223,49,143,67,48,20,46,8,2,4,17,17,8,109,17,0,1,118572,3893,114679,112975,87285,24177,480,830,94,109,1704,1602,93,8,0,1,91446,90441,70313,17746,451,665,70,1196,1005,939,62,3,0,1,91446,2473,88973,88088,69294,17621,409,653,69,42,885,826,56,2,0,1,53289,47331,5958
```

(Note: 2010 table has more columns than 2000)

```
CREATE TABLE us_counties_2010 (
    geo_name varchar(90),                    -- Name of the geography
    state_us_abbreviation varchar(2),        -- State/U.S. abbreviation
    summary_level varchar(3),                -- Summary Level
    region smallint,                         -- Region
    division smallint,                       -- Division
    state_fips varchar(2),                   -- State FIPS code
    county_fips varchar(3),                  -- County code
    area_land bigint,                        -- Area (Land) in square meters
    area_water bigint,                        -- Area (Water) in square meters
    population_count_100_percent integer,    -- Population count (100%)
    housing_unit_count_100_percent integer,  -- Housing Unit count (100%)
    internal_point_lat numeric(10,7),        -- Internal point (latitude)
    internal_point_lon numeric(10,7),        -- Internal point (longitude)

    -- This section is referred to as P1. Race:
    p0010001 integer,   -- Total population
    p0010002 integer,   -- Population of one race:
    p0010003 integer,       -- White Alone
    p0010004 integer,       -- Black or African American alone
    p0010005 integer,       -- American Indian and Alaska Native alone
    p0010006 integer,       -- Asian alone
    p0010007 integer,       -- Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander alone
    p0010008 integer,       -- Some Other Race alone
    p0010009 integer,   -- Population of two or more races
    p0010010 integer,   -- Population of two races:
    p0010011 integer,       -- White; Black or African American
    p0010012 integer,       -- White; American Indian and Alaska Native
    p0010013 integer,       -- White; Asian
    p0010014 integer,       -- White; Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander
    p0010015 integer,       -- White; Some Other Race
    p0010016 integer,       -- Black or African American; American Indian and Alaska Native
    p0010017 integer,       -- Black or African American; Asian
    p0010018 integer,       -- Black or African American; Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander
    p0010019 integer,       -- Black or African American; Some Other Race
    p0010020 integer,       -- American Indian and Alaska Native; Asian
    p0010021 integer,       -- American Indian and Alaska Native; Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander
    p0010022 integer,       -- American Indian and Alaska Native; Some Other Race
    p0010023 integer,       -- Asian; Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander
    p0010024 integer,       -- Asian; Some Other Race
    p0010025 integer,       -- Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander; Some Other Race
    p0010026 integer,   -- Population of three races
    p0010047 integer,   -- Population of four races
    p0010063 integer,   -- Population of five races
    p0010070 integer,   -- Population of six races

    -- This section is referred to as P2. HISPANIC OR LATINO, AND NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO BY RACE
    p0020001 integer,   -- Total
    p0020002 integer,   -- Hispanic or Latino
    p0020003 integer,   -- Not Hispanic or Latino:
    p0020004 integer,   -- Population of one race:
    p0020005 integer,       -- White Alone
    p0020006 integer,       -- Black or African American alone
    p0020007 integer,       -- American Indian and Alaska Native alone
    p0020008 integer,       -- Asian alone
    p0020009 integer,       -- Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander alone
    p0020010 integer,       -- Some Other Race alone
    p0020011 integer,   -- Two or More Races
    p0020012 integer,   -- Population of two races
    p0020028 integer,   -- Population of three races
    p0020049 integer,   -- Population of four races
    p0020065 integer,   -- Population of five races
    p0020072 integer,   -- Population of six races

    -- This section is referred to as P3. RACE FOR THE POPULATION 18 YEARS AND OVER
    p0030001 integer,   -- Total
    p0030002 integer,   -- Population of one race:
    p0030003 integer,       -- White alone
    p0030004 integer,       -- Black or African American alone
    p0030005 integer,       -- American Indian and Alaska Native alone
    p0030006 integer,       -- Asian alone
    p0030007 integer,       -- Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander alone
    p0030008 integer,       -- Some Other Race alone
    p0030009 integer,   -- Two or More Races
    p0030010 integer,   -- Population of two races
    p0030026 integer,   -- Population of three races
    p0030047 integer,   -- Population of four races
    p0030063 integer,   -- Population of five races
    p0030070 integer,   -- Population of six races

    -- This section is referred to as P4. HISPANIC OR LATINO, AND NOT HISPANIC OR LATINO BY RACE
    -- FOR THE POPULATION 18 YEARS AND OVER
    p0040001 integer,   -- Total
    p0040002 integer,   -- Hispanic or Latino
    p0040003 integer,   -- Not Hispanic or Latino:
    p0040004 integer,   -- Population of one race:
    p0040005 integer,   -- White alone
    p0040006 integer,   -- Black or African American alone
    p0040007 integer,   -- American Indian and Alaska Native alone
    p0040008 integer,   -- Asian alone
    p0040009 integer,   -- Native Hawaiian and Other Pacific Islander alone
    p0040010 integer,   -- Some Other Race alone
    p0040011 integer,   -- Two or More Races
    p0040012 integer,   -- Population of two races
    p0040028 integer,   -- Population of three races
    p0040049 integer,   -- Population of four races
    p0040065 integer,   -- Population of five races
    p0040072 integer,   -- Population of six races

    -- This section is referred to as H1. OCCUPANCY STATUS
    h0010001 integer,   -- Total housing units
    h0010002 integer,   -- Occupied
    h0010003 integer    -- Vacant
);
```

How to round this query?

**EDIT:** This query is able to CAST the percentile result to 1 decimal place.

```
SELECT CAST(percentile_cont(.5)
    WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY
    (CAST(c2010.p0010001 AS numeric(8,1)) - c2000.p0010001)
                  / c2000.p0010001 * 100) as numeric(4,1)) AS "50th Percentile" 
FROM us_counties_2010 as c2010 INNER JOIN us_counties_2000 as c2000
    on c2010.state_fips = c2000.state_fips
    and c2010.county_fips = c2000.county_fips;
```

Comment: Please provide sample data and expected results as tabular text so others can better help.

Comment: @GMB I added the CREATE statements and sample data.

Comment: @LucStorms Thank you for catching that. I did add the on clause, but am getting errors again. I'll update my statement here with the on clause. Error states `column "pct_change" does not exist`

Comment: "pct_change" is a calculated field, therefor can't be used in the order by for that count over.  But a calculation should be allowed: `... (order by ((c2010.p0010001 - c2000.p0010001) / c2000.p0010001)) `

Comment: @LucStorms Thank for your help. Following your remarks - I was able to get the `50th percentile`. I wonder if you could suggest how to round the result to 1 decimal place? The revised query is at the bottom of my post. Thanks again for the help you offer.

Comment: probably 2 ways, wrap the whole percentile (including the within group) in a cast to numeric.  Or use a sub-query that first calculates the rounded/casted percentage, then calculate that percentile in the outer query. Method 2 will look more readable if you want to show both the percentage and the median. Since you'll only need to do the calculation for the percentage in the subquery, and reuse the calculated column in the percentile.

Comment: @LucStorms Thanks for the suggestions and helping a beginner (in SQL) along. I got the results by CASTing the whole percentile to numeric. I will work on doing it with a subquery. (The revised query is shown at the end of my post).